# Spread operator alternative

Tags: javascript

I have the following code I received:

```
function sortByProp(...props) {
  const callback = props.pop();
  return function(a, b) {
    const v1 = retrieve(props, a);
    const v2 = retrieve(props, b);
    return callback(v1, v2);
  } 
}
```

It works great in most browsers, but not in opera. I get the following error:

```
function sortByProp(...props) {
                    ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

I visited https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator to see if there is an alternative to see if there is a polyfill for this, but I can't find one.

I call this function using these two:

```
.sort(sortByProp('key', 'k', a))
          .sort(sortByProp('key', 'n', b));
```

How can I make it so this will work in all browsers?

Comment: Remove `...props`, add `var props = arguments;`? Actually, may need to convert to an array, so `[].slice.call(arguments);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't polyfill syntax. It just doesn't work. Syntax checking happens before any logic from a polyfill can occur. What you can do is use compilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert your ES2015 code down to ES5. Or you can rewrite your function to use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
function sortByProp() {
  var props = [].slice.call(arguments);
  const callback = props.pop();
  return function(a, b) {
    const v1 = retrieve(props, a);
    const v2 = retrieve(props, b);
    return callback(v1, v2);
  } 
}
```